# Stripe / React: Set up future payments, doesn't store card payment method, returns empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm following the docs here (Set up future payments - Custom payment flow):

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web

But the user payment method doesn't get stored.
On the backend the card payment method returns empty array.

On the client side:

"StripeElements Component"

```js
import { useStripe } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { stripePaymentStart, stripePaymentSuccess } from 'redux/features/adCreation.slice';
import PaymentForm from './PaymentForm';

const StripeElements = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(stripePaymentStart());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!stripe) return;

    stripe.retrieveSetupIntent(stripeClientSecret).then(({ setupIntent }) => {
      switch (setupIntent.status) {
        case 'succeeded':
          setMessage('succeeded');
          dispatch(stripePaymentSuccess());
          break;

        case 'processing':
          setMessage('processing');
          break;

        case 'requires_payment_method':
          // Redirect your user back to your payment page to attempt collecting
          // payment again
          setMessage('requires_payment_method');
          //   setMessage('Failed to process payment details. Please try another payment method.');
          break;
        default:
          console.log(setupIntent.status);
      }
    });
  }, [stripe, stripeClientSecret, stripeConfirm, dispatch]);

  if (message === 'succeeded' && stripeConfirm) {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Box className={classes.box}>
          <CheckCircle className={classes.icon} />
          <Typography align="center">Success! Your payment method has been saved.</Typography>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    );
  }

  if (message === 'succeeded') {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Box className={classes.box}>
          <Typography align="center">Choose saved credit card / debit card.</Typography>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    );
  }

  if (message === 'processing') {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Box className={classes.box}>
          <LoadingSpinner
            in={true}
            mountOnEnter
            unmountOnExit
            timeout={400}
            size={32}
            color="#663399"
          />
          <Typography align="center">
            Processing payment details. We'll update you when processing is complete.
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    );
  }

  return <PaymentForm onStripeConfirm={() => setStripeConfirm(true)} />;
};

export default StripeElements;
```

"Payment Form Component"

```js
import { PaymentElement, useElements, useStripe } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';

const PaymentForm = ({ onStripeConfirm }) => {

  const handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) return;

    setIsLoading(true);

    const { error } = await stripe.confirmSetup({
      elements,
      redirect: 'if_required',
    });

    if (error) {
      setErrorMessage(error.message);
      dispatch(stripePaymentFailure(error.message));
    } else {
      onStripeConfirm();
    }
  };

  return (
    <form className={classes.paymentForm} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <PaymentElement className={classes.paymentElement} />
      <Button
        type="submit"
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        disabled={isLoading || !stripe || !elements}
        className={classes.submitButton}
      >
        {isLoading ? (
          <LoadingSpinner in={isLoading} mountOnEnter unmountOnExit timeout={400} size={30} />
        ) : (
          'Submit'
        )}
      </Button>
      {/* Show error message to your customers */}
      {errorMessage && <Typography align="center">{errorMessage}</Typography>}
    </form>
  );
};

export default PaymentForm;
```

Response of retrieveSetupIntent (setupIntent):

{
"id": "*********************************",
"object": "setup_intent",
"cancellation_reason": null,
"client_secret": "*********************************",
"created": 1660222675,
"description": null,
"last_setup_error": null,
"livemode": false,
"next_action": null,
"payment_method": "*********************************",
"payment_method_types": [
"card"
],
"status": "succeeded",
"usage": "off_session"
}

P.S I deleted most of the imports, and hooks usage, So I could post the reset of the codes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `payment_method` [field](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/object#setup_intent_object-payment_method) on the successful Setup Intent will be the ID for the generated Payment Method [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object) created by the Setup Intent. This is what you'd persist in your own database for usage in future payments.

Comment: Thanks, it was an issue on the backend.
sorry for my late reply.